# How to get information about the certificate?

Tags: c++, qt, ssl

I have code:

```
QSslSocket * serverSocket = new QSslSocket();
serverSocket->setPrivateKey("some.key");
serverSocket->setLocalCertificate("some.crt");
serverSocket->startServerEncryption();
if(serverSocket->waitForEncrypted()) {
 ...
```

In this case I use a const key and certificate.  I would like to receive information about the client's certificate and install it on the basis of different keys and certificates for the connection.

In the documentation, I found that there is a method serverSocket->peerCertificate().
But I can not get information about the client certificate with this method. Help please.